# Can't pass empty value into angular.isString(value) funtion

Tags: angularjs

I am working with one of Angular library and there is one attribute which tests value if it is a string with `angular.isString(value)` function and I want to pass empty string there but it does not work, any ideas?

I tried '' and ' ' and false but nothing worked, note it is html attribute.

EDIT:

Here is the code which checks if value is string, but I think it does not accept empty value:

```
if (angular.isString(value) && value.length === 0) {
   value = attrs.placeholder;
}
```

Here is html attribute:

```
placeholder=" "
```

Here is the default value for this attribute:

```
placeholder: [String, 'Add a tag'],
```

So if pass empty string I always get 'Add a tag' placeholder.

Comment: If you show your code, someone might be able to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the isString function definition  (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/angular/code.angularjs.org/master/1.4.6/angular.js)

```
 function isString(value) {return typeof value === 'string';}
```

any thing which has type "string" should be true.

If you try this in your browser console you should be able to see "" and " " consider as String.

```
var t = "";
undefined
typeof(t)
"string"
```